# Eclipse LUNA crashes frequently without any error

Tags: windows-7, java, eclipse

I have followed a several of the posts on StackOverflow and SuperUser to check for solutions for my problem, but haven't got one. This is the environment that I'm currently struggling to get my ECLIPSE LUNA up and running.

Environment Details:

- Java 8 (1.8.0_111)
- Windows 7, 64 bit OS
- Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- Build id: 20150219-0600

This is my current `eclipse-ini` file with modifications from various sources / forums and eclipse websites.

```
-clean
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

These are the errors that I'm getting when I'm trying to run my `eclipse.exe`

[image]

And this is the full stack-trace that I was able to get by replacing javaw.exe to java.exe under `-vm` argument in the `eclipse.ini` file.

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: E:\ProjectWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration\logback.1.5.1.20150109-1820.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Exception in thread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.append(Path.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getChildren(DeltaDataTree.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.getChildIDs(ElementTree.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.getChildren(ElementTree.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getChildren(Container.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.members(Container.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.members(Container.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeFolderChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragmentRoot.computeChildren(PackageFragmentRoot.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.initializePackageNames(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.getProjectCache(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProjectElementInfo.newNameLookup(JavaProjectElementInfo.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2329)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.<init>(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:789)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1247)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:108)
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.isVisible(Shell.java:1170)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManagerUtil.getDefaultParent(ProgressManagerUtil.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.<init>(InternalDialog.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler$1.run(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3817)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.isVisible(Shell.java:1170)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManagerUtil.getDefaultParent(ProgressManagerUtil.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.<init>(InternalDialog.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler$1.run(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3817)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Any help in resolving this issue will be much appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Comment: The answer is in your exception trace: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. You need to allocate more memory for eclipse. Increase the Xms and Xmx values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your tip @DavidPostill, that helped.

I'm adding the `-vmargs` parameters that I added to my `eclipse.ini` file to solve my problem, for others to refer, should the same issue be faced by anyone else.

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:PermSize=64M 
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Adding / Modifying the above parameters has helped me resolve the issue.

Thanks for all your help!!!